Does a T gate via teleportation use 1 magic state for $n$ T gates or $n$ magic states for $n$ T gates?
In Magic State Distillation: Not as Costly as You Think,

Shows that a $P_\frac{\pi}{8}$ gate can per done on $n$ qubits using 1 magic state. When I simulate this circuit though, it doesn't seem to provide the correct output.
I first start by simulating an X gate using T gates without any teleportation 100 times
0: ───H───T───T───T───T───H───M───

This gives the right result: {1: 100}
I then do the same as the above but implement the first T gate with teleportation
                     ┌─────┐
0: ───H───────M(Z)────S────────Z───T───T───T───H───M───
              ║       ║        ║
1: ───H───T───M(Z)────╫M(X)────╫───────────────────────
              ║       ║║       ║
a: ═══════════@═══════^╬═══════╬═══════════════════════
                       ║       ║
b: ════════════════════@═══════^═══════════════════════

We get the same counts as the first circuit. Looking good so far.
We then simulate the circuit from Figure 1 of the "Not as Costly as you think paper"
                     ┌────────┐   ┌────┐
0: ───H───────M(Z)────S────────────Z───────T───T───T───H───M───
              ║       ║            ║
1: ───H───────M(Z)────╫S───────────╫Z──────T───T───T───H───M───
              ║       ║║           ║║
2: ───H───────M(Z)────╫╫S──────────╫╫Z─────T───T───T───H───M───
              ║       ║║║          ║║║
3: ───H───────M(Z)────╫╫╫S─────────╫╫╫Z────T───T───T───H───M───
              ║       ║║║║         ║║║║
4: ───H───T───M(Z)────╫╫╫╫M(X)─────╫╫╫╫────────────────────────
              ║       ║║║║║        ║║║║
a: ═══════════@═══════^^^^╬════════╬╬╬╬════════════════════════
                          ║        ║║║║
b: ═══════════════════════@════════^^^^════════════════════════
                     └────────┘   └────┘


This one does not give the same counts, which makes me suspect that the T gate is not being implemented correctly.
We then use a magic state for each T gate we want to implement
              ┌────────────────┐   ┌────────────────────┐   ┌────┐
0: ───H────────M(Z)─────────────────S────────────────────────Z───────T───T───T───H───M───
               ║                    ║                        ║
1: ───H────────╫───M(Z)─────────────╫S───────────────────────╫Z──────T───T───T───H───M───
               ║   ║                ║║                       ║║
2: ───H────────╫───╫───M(Z)─────────╫╫S──────────────────────╫╫Z─────T───T───T───H───M───
               ║   ║   ║            ║║║                      ║║║
3: ───H────────╫───╫───╫───M(Z)─────╫╫╫S─────────────────────╫╫╫Z────T───T───T───H───M───
               ║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║                     ║║║║
4: ───H───T────M(Z)╫───╫───╫────────╫╫╫╫M(X)─────────────────╫╫╫╫────────────────────────
               ║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║║                    ║║║║
5: ───H───T────╫───M(Z)╫───╫────────╫╫╫╫╫───M(X)─────────────╫╫╫╫────────────────────────
               ║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║║   ║                ║║║║
6: ───H───T────╫───╫───M(Z)╫────────╫╫╫╫╫───╫───M(X)─────────╫╫╫╫────────────────────────
               ║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║║   ║   ║            ║║║║
7: ───H───T────╫───╫───╫───M(Z)─────╫╫╫╫╫───╫───╫───M(X)─────╫╫╫╫────────────────────────
               ║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║
a: ════════════@═══╬═══╬═══╬════════^╬╬╬╬═══╬═══╬═══╬════════╬╬╬╬════════════════════════
                   ║   ║   ║         ║║║║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║
b: ════════════════@═══╬═══╬═════════^╬╬╬═══╬═══╬═══╬════════╬╬╬╬════════════════════════
                       ║   ║          ║║║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║
c: ════════════════════@═══╬══════════^╬╬═══╬═══╬═══╬════════╬╬╬╬════════════════════════
                           ║           ║║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║
d: ════════════════════════@═══════════^╬═══╬═══╬═══╬════════╬╬╬╬════════════════════════
                                        ║   ║   ║   ║        ║║║║
e: ═════════════════════════════════════@═══╬═══╬═══╬════════^╬╬╬════════════════════════
                                            ║   ║   ║         ║║║
f: ═════════════════════════════════════════@═══╬═══╬═════════^╬╬════════════════════════
                                                ║   ║          ║║
g: ═════════════════════════════════════════════@═══╬══════════^╬════════════════════════
                                                    ║           ║
h: ═════════════════════════════════════════════════@═══════════^════════════════════════
              └────────────────┘   └────────────────────┘   └────┘


This one works as it should.
What's going on? Am I reading gate teleporation figures incorrectly again?
I've pasted the code used to generate these circuits below to aid in reproduction of the results.
import collections
import cirq


def x_gate_on_1_qubit():
    return cirq.Circuit(
        cirq.H(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.T(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.T(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.T(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.T(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.H(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.measure(cirq.q(0)),
    )


def gate_teleportation_on_1_qubit():
    return cirq.Circuit(
        cirq.H.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1)),
        cirq.T(cirq.q(1)),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.Z(cirq.q(0)) * cirq.Z(cirq.q(1)), key="a"),
        cirq.S(cirq.q(0)).with_classical_controls("a"),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.X(cirq.q(1)), key="b"),
        cirq.Z(cirq.q(0)).with_classical_controls("b"),
        cirq.T(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.T(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.T(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.H(cirq.q(0)),
        cirq.measure_each(cirq.q(0)),
    )


def gate_teleportation_on_4_qubits_with_1_magic_state():
    return cirq.Circuit(
        cirq.H.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3), cirq.q(4)),
        cirq.T(cirq.q(4)),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(
            cirq.Z(cirq.q(0))
            * cirq.Z(cirq.q(1))
            * cirq.Z(cirq.q(2))
            * cirq.Z(cirq.q(3))
            * cirq.Z(cirq.q(4)),
            key="a",
        ),
        cirq.S(cirq.q(0)).with_classical_controls("a"),
        cirq.S(cirq.q(1)).with_classical_controls("a"),
        cirq.S(cirq.q(2)).with_classical_controls("a"),
        cirq.S(cirq.q(3)).with_classical_controls("a"),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.X(cirq.q(4)), key="b"),
        cirq.Z(cirq.q(0)).with_classical_controls("b"),
        cirq.Z(cirq.q(1)).with_classical_controls("b"),
        cirq.Z(cirq.q(2)).with_classical_controls("b"),
        cirq.Z(cirq.q(3)).with_classical_controls("b"),
        cirq.T.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
        cirq.T.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
        cirq.T.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
        cirq.H.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
        cirq.measure_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
    )


def gate_teleportation_on_4_qubits_with_4_magic_states():
    return cirq.Circuit(
        cirq.H.on_each(
            cirq.q(0),
            cirq.q(1),
            cirq.q(2),
            cirq.q(3),
            cirq.q(4),
            cirq.q(5),
            cirq.q(6),
            cirq.q(7),
        ),
        cirq.T.on_each(cirq.q(4), cirq.q(5), cirq.q(6), cirq.q(7)),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.Z(cirq.q(0)) * cirq.Z(cirq.q(4)), key="a"),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.Z(cirq.q(1)) * cirq.Z(cirq.q(5)), key="b"),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.Z(cirq.q(2)) * cirq.Z(cirq.q(6)), key="c"),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.Z(cirq.q(3)) * cirq.Z(cirq.q(7)), key="d"),
        cirq.S(cirq.q(0)).with_classical_controls("a"),
        cirq.S(cirq.q(1)).with_classical_controls("b"),
        cirq.S(cirq.q(2)).with_classical_controls("c"),
        cirq.S(cirq.q(3)).with_classical_controls("d"),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.X(cirq.q(4)), key="e"),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.X(cirq.q(5)), key="f"),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.X(cirq.q(6)), key="g"),
        cirq.measure_single_paulistring(cirq.X(cirq.q(7)), key="h"),
        cirq.Z(cirq.q(0)).with_classical_controls("e"),
        cirq.Z(cirq.q(1)).with_classical_controls("f"),
        cirq.Z(cirq.q(2)).with_classical_controls("g"),
        cirq.Z(cirq.q(3)).with_classical_controls("h"),
        cirq.T.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
        cirq.T.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
        cirq.T.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
        cirq.H.on_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
        cirq.measure_each(cirq.q(0), cirq.q(1), cirq.q(2), cirq.q(3)),
    )


sim = cirq.Simulator()

x_gate_on_1_qubit_circuit = x_gate_on_1_qubit()
result = sim.run(x_gate_on_1_qubit_circuit, repetitions=100)
assert result.histogram(key="q(0)") == collections.Counter({1: 100})

gate_teleportation_on_1_qubit_circuit = gate_teleportation_on_1_qubit()
result = sim.run(gate_teleportation_on_1_qubit_circuit, repetitions=100)
assert result.histogram(key="q(0)") == collections.Counter({1: 100})

gate_teleportation_on_4_qubits_with_1_magic_state_circuit = (
    gate_teleportation_on_4_qubits_with_1_magic_state()
)
result = sim.run(
    gate_teleportation_on_4_qubits_with_1_magic_state_circuit, repetitions=100
)
assert result.histogram(key="q(0)") == collections.Counter({1: 100})


gate_teleportation_on_4_qubits_with_4_magic_states_circuit = (
    gate_teleportation_on_4_qubits_with_4_magic_states()
)
result = sim.run(
    gate_teleportation_on_4_qubits_with_4_magic_states_circuit, repetitions=100
)
assert result.histogram(key="q(0)") == collections.Counter({1: 100})



The gate that you are applying by teleportation is $(Z^{\otimes 4})^{1/4}$. This is different from $(Z^{1/4})^{\otimes 4} = T^{\otimes 4}$. For example, $(Z^{\otimes 4})^{1/4}$ doesn't phase the $|1100\rangle$ state whereas $(Z^{1/4})^{\otimes 4}$ phases it by 90 degrees.

Here's a quirk circuit with the two gates, so you can see they do different things.

That means Figure 1 from the "Not as Costly as you think" paper is misleading, no?

@VictoryOmole No, the figure and caption are both clearly describing one non-clifford gate not multiple.

I'm used to controlled gates being multi-qubit gates but in this case the $P\frac{\pi}{8}$ gate is not controlled. Doesn't that mean that it can be broken down into $n$ single qubit gates?

@VictoryOmole No. It's inherently a multi-qubit gate. If you break it down into single gates you will phase the wrong states by the wrong amounts, as you've seen in your simulations. This is sortof akin to expecting a QFT to decompose into single qubit Hadamards when it's not controlled; it's just not how that works.
